# Proxy configuration in Twitter4j

Tags: java, proxy, twitter4j

I am behind a proxy. I have the proxy details. However I am not sure how to use these details to connect to twitter.

I have looked at the documentations so I am aware of the methods:

`setHttpProxy(java.lang.String proxyHost, int proxyPort) 
 void setHttpProxyAuth(java.lang.String proxyUser, java.lang.String proxyPass)`

But it is not possible to use them as, Eclipse draws a red line underneath them. 
Do I need to import or initialise anything before using these methods?

Comment: What does "can not use them" mean? Any exceptions?

Comment: The Methods are not recognised by Eclipse. It draws a red line underneath it. Hence, why I asked if I need to import anything.

Comment: Maybe the version of the documentation you are looking at and the version of the library you are using do not match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try adding the properties

```
http.proxyHost=yourProxyHost
http.proxyPort=yourProxyPort
```

to the twitter4j.properties ?

More about properties for twitter4j at http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html

Note that twitter4j lacks proxy-support in versions earlier then 2.1.4 ref this thread:
[Twitter4j HTTPClient ProxyServer and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518348/twitter4j-httpclient-proxyserver-and-java)

Hope it helps :)